# Better way to handle hash URLs for AJAX sites

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, back-button, history.js

Unless this is HTML 5 where I can easily use history.pushState() to manipulate URL when AJAX loads additional piece of page, I find it inconvenient to handle pages registered with hash mark in URL address bar.

For example, page item1.html is loaded. User clicks next item - item2.html page is loaded with AJAX. Address is changed in the browser to item1.html#item2.html.

Now as user sends this URL to a friend or bookmarks it, I want to make sure item2.html is loaded.

Approach 1) JavaScript will redirect URL item1.html#item2.html to item2.html. Disadvantage: item1.html is loaded and flickers for a second before redirect.

Approach 2) load item1.html and hide item1 content, then load item2.html with Ajax request. Disadvantage: item1 content can still be visible (unless I hide it with visibility none which may be bad for SE's)

Better approach? There must be a great solution I am missing that many big sites implement.

Comment: Why can't you use pushState to change the URL to item2.html?

Comment: I use it for HTML 5 browsers. But what about IE? And other older browsers?

Comment: Do what github does. Don't use ajax, and do a *real* redirect for shitty browsers. IE is the only "older browser" now that Firefox almost auto-updates and Chrome auto-updates. Anyone using IE6 doesn't deserve a smooth experience anyway.

Comment: I never saw Github in IE. Thanks for pointing out. Sadly, IE is still widely used browser and I would not want to take an AJAX feature away.

Comment: Are you building for a client, a corporation, or the masses? If the first or second, I understand your position. If you're building a public-access application, I would just follow the leaders in the space, and Github is one of them. It really doesn't feel *that bad* in IE, but it's awesome in chrome, firefox, opera, and safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of the # part as a url to a file. It's a logical state for the page to be in.

For you I think that means having like a page.html, which maybe has no real content on its own. Then you have page.html#item1 and page.html#item2, etc. The urls are always consistent. You'd never really directly navigate to item1.html or item2.html.

Comment: What about search engines? if item1 is AJAX call and page.html is empty, then the site is screwed.

Comment: I'd first make all work without js and then add js features ([unobtrustive js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)). In this case you avoid search engine crawler problems ans users with js enabled get a more convenient version of your site. So in your case your normal links would be `<a href="item/2">Next</a>`. Then you append your ajax behaviour after the dom loaded.

Comment: Great recommendation and I already have my site done without JS. Now I apply dynamic functionality. The question is what approach to use.

Comment: I'd go for approach 2. You may also [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) `item1` from the dom completely. Why? Personally I don't like redirecting via js and it would go against your approach to make your site more dynamic and it may consume more traffic than ajax requesting the content. If you look at twitter ([e.g. here](http://twitter.com/#!/BoltClock/status/132535159521157120)) you first see the blue page flashing and then the content gets loaded. So big sites don't do any magic either.

Comment: I'm all for SEO and unobtrusive js, but it sounded like you were already going for a "single page app" approach. Absolutely make it work without all that if you can. The crux of my point is that the # part isn't a url, its a logical state for the app which means whatever you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

As IL outlined above, you want the 'shell' of your AJAX application (the file immediately preceding the hash tag in the URL, e.g: page.html) to serve as nothing more than a container which loads item1.html, item2.html, etc. via AJAX. In order to ensure that the resource referenced after the hash tag is loaded into the empty shell when the user first arrives at your application, you'll want to call a function at window.onload (or $(document).ready() if you're using jQuery) that reads location.hash into the appropriate AJAX call, with a default scenario if location.hash is undefined, blank, or a value that returns an AJAX error.

In order to 'prettify' your URL for easy entry and indexing in search engines, you'll want to set up a .httaccess file at the root of your site that rewrites a clean URL (e.g: http://example.com/item1) into a file location with a hash value (e.g: http://example.com/page.html#item1) so that your engine can understand it and load the appropriate resource.